# Check string for link

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I have rather long entries being submitted to a database.

How can I create a function to see if this entry has a link within it?  Can someone get me started?

Pretty much, I want the function to find any `<a`, `<a href` or any other related link instances within a string.

I'd prefer not to throw the entry into an array.  Are there any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: So with link you mean the `a` element?

Comment: Ah, ok. Your markup just got eaten by the system.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295761/count-html-links-in-a-string-and-add-a-list

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) to find the HTML tag

Comment: The <center> can not hold! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Ok, cool. That's an interesting read. I would agree that regex wouldn't be ideal for every case, but the poster asked to find any "<a" or "<a href" tags. You're telling me that regex can't do that? I beg to differ

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay away from RegEx, you could use an ugly combination of strpos and substr to find `"<a "` extract that, etc.

Something ugly like this (this only finds the first link, it will fail with bad code, and it doesn't find ' (which is invalid XHTML))  p.s. this is a bad idea:

```
function findLink($string) {
  $pos = strpos($string, "<a ");
  if ($pos === false)
    return false;

  $string = substr($string, $pos);
  $pos = strpos($string, "href");
  $string = substr($string, $pos);

  // First quote
  $pos = strpos($string, '"');
  $string = substr($string, $pos + 1);

  // Last quote
  $pos = strpos($string, '"');
  $string = substr($string, 0, $pos);

  if (trim($string) != "")
    return $string;
  return false;
}
```

I'm sure you could also try tokenizing the string?

```
$token = strtok($string, "\"'");
while ($token !== false) {
  // Look for anything with a link in it
  str_replace(array("http://", "www", "ftp://"), "", ltrim($string), $count);
  if ($count > 0)
    return $string;
  $token = strtok($string, "\"'");
}
return false;
```

Note: these are NOT great ways to do this.